# Convert error text from response api using javascript, react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, lodash

I have call api from server, and I handle error text from api.

Here is response from api.

```
{
    response : {
        data: {
            "errorCode": "99",
            "errorType": "UNEXPECTED_ERROR",
            "developerMessage": "400 : [{\"errorCode\":\"91\",\"developerMessage\":\"{\\\"errorCode\\\":\\\"10\\\",\\\"developerMessage\\\":\\\"Offer code not exits\\\"}\"}]",
        }
    }
}
```

I want to show error text from `developerMessage` prop. Like so: `developerMessage: "Offer code not exits"`.

I used lodash to get that error, but not what I wanted.

```
const errorMessage = _.get(error, ['response', 'data', 'developerMessage', 400]);
```

How do I fix it to make it work?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `parse` your response data using `JSON.parse()` at multi-level down the object hierarchy.

```js
let responseData = {
    response: {
        data: {
            "errorCode": "99",
            "errorType": "UNEXPECTED_ERROR",
            "developerMessage": "400 : [{\"errorCode\":\"91\",\"developerMessage\":\"{\\\"errorCode\\\":\\\"10\\\",\\\"developerMessage\\\":\\\"Offer code not exits\\\"}\"}]"
        }
    }
};

const getErrorMsg = (inputData) => {
    const devMsg = inputData.response.data.developerMessage;
    const errorMsg = JSON.parse(devMsg.slice(devMsg.indexOf("[")));
    return JSON.parse(errorMsg[0].developerMessage).developerMessage;
}

console.log(getErrorMsg(responseData));
```